# Input Field Validation Not Working If Using Virtual Keyboard on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

My input field is integrated with virtual keyboard. If I type manually it's working, but if I use the virtual keyboard (I use JKeyboard) it does not work. Any trick for my problem?
Example problem is:
1. I use min length and max length validation. When `digit < 9` or `digit > 12` will show the error automatically before the button is clicked. But if I type with the virtual keyboard it does not work.
2. I have tried to use jquery for validation and have tried to use `maxlength="12"` for force stop if more than 12. But if I type with the virtual keyboard the digit is still can.